# Can't connect to my MongoDB DataBase, getting this error "Server Selection Timed Out After 3000ms" on Mongodb Compass

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-compass

This is the error that I is being shown on my terminal.

```
{
message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017',
  name: 'MongooseServerSelectionError',
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

My Code for connecting to DataBase in this:-

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/playground", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("database connected");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Could not connect", err);
  });
```

Everything was working fine until I shut down my laptop. I don't know why the Mongodb compass is showing me this error "Server selection timed out after 30000 ms", I am working on the localhost, only

Comment: try this as your URI - "mongodb://localhost/playground"

Comment: Also let me know the error message:

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.on("error", error => {
  console.error(`→ ${error.message}`); // tells you whether or not the connection to mongodb was successful
});

Comment: @Leafyshark I tried  "mongodb://localhost/playground" as my url and got this error   "ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017" .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said "...*everything was working until you shut down your computer*...", it's most likely the [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/index.html) process exited on shut down. Can you try restarting the `mongod` process and connect again, details on how to start the process are here [For Windows](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#start-your-mongodb-database) and [For Mac](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb-community-edition).

To avoid having issues like this again when you restart or shut down your system, consider starting the mongod process as a service, how you do that is dependant on the OS you are using, however, you can find complete set of instructions on the installation page. For example, if you are using a Mac, instructions are [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#run-mongodb-community-edition).

Answer (score 12):

If you have recently updated your Node.js runtime environment to version v18.12.1, you might notice that the MongoDB URL that you were using to connect to your local MongoDB instance has changed from 'mongodb://localhost:27017' to 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'. This change is because using "localhost" can sometimes lead to issues with certain network configurations. By using the IP address "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost", you can avoid these issues and ensure that your application can connect to MongoDB reliably. Therefore, it's generally recommended to use IP addresses rather than hostnames when connecting to MongoDB to avoid issues with DNS resolution and network configuration.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

Extending @Maduekew's answers, on Windows, click on services to filter out services only, then search for MongoDB, if the status column says `Stopped`, right-click and then select `Start`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I tried starting MongoDB from services, but it does not start so i run mongod from the terminal to start MongoDB and change the localhost section of my connection string to `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the similar issue,
my node version is 18.17.0
by simply changing the connection string to

from  `mongodb://localhost:27017/`  to this   `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/`

solve my issue

Answer (score 1):

Try with 127.0.0.1:27017 rather than localhost:27017 . it really works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

By changing the localhost:27017 to 127.0.01:27017 works fine without any issues.

```
   const mongoose=require('mongoose')
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/your-datbase-name',
   {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
   }).then(()=>{
   console.log("connected")
   }).catch((e)=>{
   console.log('error occured')
   console.log(e)
   })
```

final code looks like

```
   const mongoose=require('mongoose')
   mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/your-datbase- 
   name',
   {
   useNewUrlParser: true,
   useUnifiedTopology: true
   }).then(()=>{
   console.log("connected")
   }).catch((e)=>{
   console.log('error occured')
   console.log(e)
   })
```

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran mongo and mongod in terminal it didn't work.

solution for windows but should be similar to mac

on windows open task manager || Ctrl + shift + ESC > select service tab > search for mongo db > right click > start service